# The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish a newly created asp.net 4.6 web project to Azure web apps and receiving the following error:

remote: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.** Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\home\site\repository\WebApp\WebApp.csproj]

Everything builds fine via Visual Studio 2015 on my local machine. I thought Azure web apps were all set to support VS 2015 RTM upon release, but it would appear they do not have MSBuild 14.0 installed. Is there a work around or a roadmap for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Apps doesn't support ASP.NET 4.6 yet. It's on it's way though, so stay tuned.

Comment: Yep. I had to change the ToolsVersion property in the .csproj file to 12.0 and fix a few minor things elsewhere, but it worked fine. I wasn't really using any 4.6 specific features anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Here was the fix for me. 
Using `Nuget` Package Manager, remove these two packages if referenced:

1. `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`
2. `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`

After that, run a rebuild. This ensured that the build was not trying to use a specific build exe. Click here for the
[Diff against previous revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zdhq.png)

Comment: Updating above packages fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Removed Microsoft.Net.Compilers helped.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have to edit my .csproj file and find below lines and delete them

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
```

Now everything is fine,