# microsoft.codeanalysis.buildtasks.csc task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, quickbooks-online

I am working on QuickBook Online integration with .Net application and I am facing this issue in my visual studio 2013 tried solutions given on stackoverflow like :

[BuildTasks.Csc task could not be loaded from the assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150204/buildtasks-csc-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly)

[The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620168/the-microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-task-could-not-be-loaded)

but dint find helpful so any other solution ??

**issue I am facing is as follows :**

> "Error 1   The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\prompt\Downloads\OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK-master(1)\OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK-master\OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.1\build..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK "

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on quickbooks online integration .
Visual studio 2013

Started upgrading OAuth 1.0a to OAuth 2.0 ,On the way i struct on same issue .
Resolved the issue after 2-3 hour of struggle ,feel like sharing .

*I just followed following steps to get out it :*

1. Step 1st : Close all instance of visual studio 2013 (or other
   version)
2. Step 2nd : Install ,[Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)
3. Step 3rd : Clear files from following :

   ```
           RUN -> %temp%
           RUN -> prefetch
   ```
4. Step 4th : Open Visual studio 2013 and Manage you project .
5. Finally : Make sure .test project should not be there .It's getting
   multiple issues (Actually in my case).

*Currently Quickbooks are using following nuget packages which can be installed from **Pacakage Manager Console** :*

1. Install-Package DevDefined.OAuth -Version 0.2.0
2. Install-Package IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3 -Version 4.0.0
3. Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
   -Version 1.0.7
4. Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.3.2
5. Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.3

   *Hope It helps !!*

Answer (score -2):

what helped me is as follows just for information

http://marcusmckibben.com/2016/06/14/microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-error/#comment-67

Comment: This is a perfect example of why just posting links as answers is a bad idea, because that one's dead now.

Comment: Indeed, it's very frustrating. Just copy and paste the comment into the text box, how hard is that?

Comment: found it on https://web.archive.org/web/20171115163924/http://marcusmckibben.com:80/2016/06/14/microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-error/ - "I installed the software from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and the problem was solved."